# How can I pass a file to unittest.mock.mock_open()?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a function that reads a log file and filters results, and I want to test to make sure it is filtering correctly.

**My code**

```py
import os
import random
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

__SAMPLE_LOG__ = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "apps/tests/log_viewer/sample_logs/sample_manager_log.log")

class FilterLog(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with open(__SAMPLE_LOG__) as f:
            self.sample_data = f.read()

    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable = mock_open, read_data = self.sample_data)
    def test_filterDate(self, mock_file):
        
        day = '08'
        month = '08'
        year = '2019'
        results = filter_log(filter_by = 'date', day = day, month = month, year = year)

        self.assertEqual(open(settings.ACTIVITY_LOG_FILE).read(), self.sample_data)
```

**The error**

> @patch('builtins.open', new_callable = mock_open, read_data = self.sample_data)
>
> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

**My question**

How am I supposed to pass the data into `mock_open()`? I feel like it's bad practice to have a `with open() ... read()` at the top of the file, nor can I make this a class variable (can I?), so what are my options?

**What the documentation says**

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) `read_data` takes in a string, so somehow I need to read the file into a variable and pass it in. But where is it appropriate to read the file? At the top of the module, at the beginning of the class, or in `setUp()`?

Comment: Where did you define `sample_data` function?

Comment: @sagarr `sample_data` is a variable that is defined in the `setUp()` class method

Comment: I just moved the `with open() as f:` logic to the class level, and it seems to work. Is this acceptable practice? EDIT: Never mind. When I do this, `read_data` gets passed the correct value for `sample_data`, but this variable is not accessible inside my class method.

Comment: `self.data` wont work in `@patch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I took the sample_data out of class.

```
import os
import random
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

__SAMPLE_LOG__ = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "apps/tests/log_viewer/sample_logs/sample_manager_log.log")

# read your test data in sample_data
with open(__SAMPLE_LOG__) as f:
    sample_data = f.read()

class FilterLog(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.open', new_callable = mock_open, read_data = sample_data)
    def test_filterDate(self, mock_file):

        day = '08'
        month = '08'
        year = '2019'
        results = filter_log(filter_by = 'date', day = day, month = month, year = year)

        self.assertEqual(open(settings.ACTIVITY_LOG_FILE).read(), sample_data)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Is this good practice to read in a file like this at the top of a module?

Comment: Yes, by doing so you read data once and can be shared among other TC too.